# SQL Server to SQLite query translation error

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, translation

To calculate the MPG values from a `Fuel` table I'm using this SQL Server query which works great:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN Fuel.Quantity = 0 THEN 0 
       ELSE (Fuel.Odometer - ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.Odometer FROM Fuel AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.MainID = Fuel.MainID AND Dupe.FuelingDateTime < Fuel.FuelingDateTime ORDER BY Dupe.FuelingDateTime DESC, Dupe.FuelID),0)) / Fuel.Quantity 
    END AS MPG 
FROM Fuel 
WHERE MainID = 1
```

When I translate it to SQLite query I get an error:

> Near "1" : syntax error

The SQLite query is:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN Fuel.Quantity = 0 THEN 0 
ELSE 
(Fuel.Odometer - IFNULL((Select TOP 1 Dupe.Odometer FROM Fuel As Dupe WHERE Dupe.MainID = Fuel.MainID AND Dupe.FuelingDateTime < Fuel.FuelingDateTime ORDER BY Dupe.FuelingDateTime DESC, Dupe.FuelID),0)) / Fuel.Quantity 
END As MPG 
FROM Fuel 
WHERE MainID = 1
```

Is it the temporary table ('Dupe')? How do I write the query in SQLite?

Comment: Notice: your question's title is bad, it should be `MS SQL to SQLite` :) SQLite uses the `SELECT .... LIMIT x OFFSET y` syntax instead of `TOP`: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: You're right.. My title is wrong. How do I change it, I don't want to mislead readers.

Comment: Thank you, biziclop. It works! I've added LIMIT 1 to the query.